# Minimal linear regression program

Tags: c++, python, bash, linear-algebra

I am running some calculations in an external machine and at the end I get X, Y pairs. I want to apply linear regression and obtain A, B, and R2. In this machine I can not install anything (it runs Linux) and has basic stuff installed on it, python, bash (of course), etc.

I wonder what would be the best approach to use a script (python, bash, etc) or program (I can compile C and C++) that gives me the linear regression coefficients without the need to add external libraries (numpy, etc)

Comment: If you can't use a library, code it yourself. Linear regression of a straight line gradient and intercept is simpler than generic linear regression: see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_linear_regression

Comment: If you can compile, you can install anything you need in your home directory (provided your disk quota will allow).  But just code it yourself in Python, linear regression is pretty much a couple of list comprehensions.

Answer (score 3):

For a single, simple, known function (as in your case: a line) it is not hard to simply code a basic least square routine from scratch (but does require some attention to detail). It is a very common assignment in introductory numeric analysis classes.

So, look up least squares on wikipedia or mathworld or in a text book and go to town.

Answer (score 1):

How about extracting the coeffs into a file, import to another machine and then use Excel/Matlab/whatever other program that does this for you?

Answer (score 1):

Hi there this is my solution that I got from the Wikipedia article on best fit line.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

// Returns true if linear fit was calculated. False otherwise.
// Algorithm adapted from:
// https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_linear_regression#Fitting_the_regression_line
template <typename PairIterator>
bool GetLinearFit(PairIterator begin_it,
                  PairIterator end_it,
                  double* out_slope,
                  double* out_yintercept) {

    if (begin_it == end_it) {
        return false;
    }

    size_t n = 0;
    double x_avg = 0;
    double y_avg = 0;

    for (PairIterator it = begin_it; it != end_it; ++it) {
        x_avg += it->first;
        y_avg += it->second;
        n++;
    }

    x_avg /= n;
    y_avg /= n;

    double numerator = 0;
    double denominator = 0;

    for (PairIterator it = begin_it; it != end_it; ++it) {
        double x_variance = it->first - x_avg;
        double y_variance = it->second - y_avg;
        numerator += (x_variance * y_variance);
        denominator += (x_variance * x_variance);
    }

    double slope = numerator / denominator;
    double yintercept = y_avg - slope*x_avg;

    *out_slope = slope;
    *out_yintercept= yintercept ;

    return true;
}

// Tests the output of GetLinearFit(...).
int main() {
    std::vector<std::pair<int, int> > data;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
      data.push_back(std::pair<int, int>(i+1, 2*i));
    }

    double slope = 0;
    double y_intercept = 0;
    GetLinearFit(data.begin(), data.end(), &slope, &y_intercept);

    std::cout << "slope: " << slope << "\n";
    std::cout << "y_intercept: " << y_intercept<< "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note that in C++ you should use references instead of pointers (for `out_slope` and `out_yintercept`).